# Shifting values from one key to another key in python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, data-structures, geojson

I've the below dictionary (Geojson):

```
'properties': {
            'fill': '#ffffff', 'fill-opacity': 1, 'stroke': '#ffffff',
'stroke-opacity': 1, 'stroke-width': 1.5, 'title': '0.00 m',
'time': '2000-01-31'
    }
```

What would be the easiest way to make it into as below, by moving certain values to new keys within properties.

```
'properties': {
        'style': {
            'fill': '#ffffff', 'fill-opacity': 1, 'stroke': '#ffffff',
'stroke-opacity': 1, 'stroke-width': 1.5, 'title': '0.00 m'
        },
        'time': '2000-01-31'
    }
}
```

Any feedback would be helpful.
Thanks.

Comment: Seems like `properties` is key. Please make it clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could [pop](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.pop) the `time` and build a new dict like this:

```
properties = {
            'fill': '#ffffff', 'fill-opacity': 1, 'stroke': '#ffffff',
'stroke-opacity': 1, 'stroke-width': 1.5, 'title': '0.00 m',
'time': '2000-01-31'
    }

time = properties.pop('time')
new_properties = {'style': properties, 'time':time}

print(new_properties)
# {'style': {'fill': '#ffffff', 'fill-opacity': 1, 'stroke': '#ffffff', 
#            'stroke-opacity': 1, 'stroke-width': 1.5, 'title': '0.00 m'},
#   'time': '2000-01-31'}
```

Comment: nice and simple!

Comment: Doesn't start with the OPs original data though :(  ... and doesn't produce what the OP asked for.  Other than that, this is wonderful!

Comment: @Steve I'm not sure of what you mean, could you clarify? The data provided by the OP is apparently a part of a larger dict, and isn't valid Python code in isolation anyway. The OP's goal is to transform the dict given here, which is exactly the one I transform here.

Comment: @VPfB That's right, but as long as this piece of code gets included in a function (which it hopefully will), and that same function doesn't refer to the time module, things will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the original data is in a dict (must be if it has a key and a value), and that the same is true for the desired result:

```
from pprint import pprint

start = {
    'properties': {
            'fill': '#ffffff', 'fill-opacity': 1, 'stroke': '#ffffff',
'stroke-opacity': 1, 'stroke-width': 1.5, 'title': '0.00 m',
'time': '2000-01-31'
    }
}

result = {
    'properties': {
        'style': start['properties'],
        'time': start['properties'].pop('time')
    },
}

pprint(result)
```

Result:

```
{'properties': {'style': {'fill': '#ffffff',
                          'fill-opacity': 1,
                          'stroke': '#ffffff',
                          'stroke-opacity': 1,
                          'stroke-width': 1.5,
                          'title': '0.00 m'},
                'time': '2000-01-31'}}
```